# Evaluating double Integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, version-9

While trying to evaluate the integral $\int_{y=0}^{x_2}\int_{x=0}^{min(x_1,y)} n (n - 1) (1 - y)^{(n - 2)}dxdy $ , Mathematica does not seem to yield any results.

```
 Integrate[n (n - 1) (1 - y)^(n - 2), {y, 0, x2}, {x, 0, Min[y, x1]}]
```

[Wolframm alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bn%20%28n%20-%201%29%20%281%20-%20y%29%5E%28n%20-%202%29,%20%7By,%200,%20x2%7D,%20%7Bx,%200,%20Min%5By,%20x1%5D%7D%5D) also fails saying standard computation time exceeded. Is there anyway to evaluate the integral? 
I also tried this,

```
Assuming[0 < x1 < x2 < 1, 
 Integrate[n (n - 1) (1 - y)^(n - 2), {y, 0, x2}, {x, 0, Min[y, x1]}]]
```

Comment: No assumptions on `n`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hopefully we're converging on the desired integral:

```
Assuming[(0 < x1 < x2 < 1), 
  Integrate[n (n - 1) (1 - y)^(n - 2), {y, 0, x2}, {x, 0, x1}]]
```

which has answer

```
(n x1 (-1 + (1 - x2)^n + x2))/(-1 + x2)
```

Though it may be that what you are after is:

```
Assuming[(0 < x1 < x2 < 1), 
  Integrate[n (n - 1) (1 - y)^(n - 2), {x, 0, x1}, {y, 0, x2}]]
```

which has answer:

x1 (n - n (1 - x2)^(-1 + n))

The difference between the two is the order of integration: the first variable given corresponds to the outermost integral, and is done last.

Comment: updated the question. I made some mistake while copying the code..

Comment: Do you want it with or without the $n$ in the integrand? It works either way.

Comment: with n..Anyway, since they are constants , doesnt matter

Comment: This is the actual integral I'm trying to evaluate: $\int_{x=0}^{x_1} \int_{y=0}^{x_2} n (n - 1) (1 - y)^{(n - 2)}dxdy $ subject to $0<x<y<1$ and $0<x_1<x_2<1$

Comment: @AIB: You still haven't answered my question. No assumptions on $n$? BTW, you might be interested in `Boole[]`.

Comment: Yes.. $n \ge 2$

Comment: Yes..Adding the constrained on $n$, solved my issue..
`Assuming[(n > 2), 
 Integrate[n (n - 1) (1 - y)^(n - 2), {x, 0, x1}, {y, x, x2}]]`
Thanks!